# PHP - can't find Azure class createcontaineroptions

Tags: php, class, azure

I am following this tutorial on using globs in Azure storage with PHP:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-php-how-to-use-blobs/

I used composer to get all the necessary dependencies. Here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "pear",
            "url": "https://pear.php.net"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "pear-pear.php.net/mail_mime" : "*",
        "pear-pear.php.net/http_request2" : "*",
        "pear-pear.php.net/mail_mimedecode" : "*",
        "microsoft/windowsazure": "*"
    }
}
```

I do "composer update" and it appears to get everything needed.

In PHP I do:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor\autoload.php';


use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\CreateContainerOptions;
use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\PublicAccessType;
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException;

$createContainerOptions = new CreateContainerOptions();
```

And that gives an error:

Fatal error: Class 'WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\CreateContainerOptions' not found in C:\myproject\azure.php on line 18.

I did print_r(get_declared_classes()); and sure enough, CreateContainerOptions is not in the list.

Can you please tell me what is wrong with my require or use statements that it doesn't pull in the CreateContainerOptions class?

Thank you!

Comment: can you add    $blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString); before your $createContainerOptions = new CreateContainerOptions();  then try again?

Comment: Hi, any update now?

Answer (score 0):

As the latest version of Azure SDK for PHP, the Storage SDK has changed the repository to https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php. You can check the structure in `vendor/microsoft` folder.

And also, the namespace of `CreateContainerOptions` has changed to `MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\Models\CreateContainerOptions`. Please refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/src/Blob/Models/CreateContainerOptions.php#L25.

So, to implement storage operations via latest PHP SDK, please refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.